# Ajax call back falling before going into the webmethod function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Here is my Ajax call :

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ProductDetail.aspx/AddCart",
            data: '{productId:' + 4 + ',productTypeId:' + 0 + ',quantity:' + 1 + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                alert('successful');
                refreshCart();
            },
            complete: function () {
                alert('Completed');
                refreshCart();
            }
        });
```

It give alert('Completed') and then going to the webmethod function but I need it after my server side code completed. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: The alert will not happen until after your server returns data. Don't have your server return data until you are ready for it to happen. More than likely what's really happening is an error is occurring (such as invalid json) and you are instantly getting to the complete callback.

Comment: What is "the webmethod function?"  Does `successful` get alerted?

Comment: are you debugging with VS?

Comment: @KevinB I have returned data, but Completed alert shown before go to function

Comment: @cagin that confirms my suspicion. you are getting an Error, because you aren't getting "Successful". try my code below to get the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Changing this:

```
complete: function () {
    alert('Completed');
    refreshCart();
}
```

To this:

```
complete: function (result,stat) {
    alert(stat);
    refreshCart();
}
```

And seeing what you get. If you get 'error' in any form, you know what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Your data parameter doesn't contain valid json, and you are using complete instead of error. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ProductDetail.aspx/AddCart",
    data: '{"productId":' + 4 + ',"productTypeId":' + 0 + ',"quantity":' + 1 + '}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function() {
        alert('Successful');
        refreshCart();
    },
    error: function(jqxhr,status,message) {
        alert('Error: ' + message);
        refreshCart();
    }
});​
```

Comment: What is coming after "Error"?

Comment: What does `status` give you in place of `message`? `500`? If it's `500`, that would suggest a server-side issue. Did you make the changes to the JSON i suggested?

Comment: Status is error and yes I did your suggestion but the same result.

Comment: What do you get with pow-ian's suggestion? it should also give you a number.

Comment: Yes I know it should return a number but it returns just error and it is the same with pow-ian's suggestion.